# How to get parent category title for Tag view

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, template-override

I want to get my current article's category and parent category link into my page.
I get the category via the following code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = $item->core_catid;
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.title FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$id'");
$category = $db->loadResult();
echo '<p>'.$category.'</p>';
```

But I do not manage to get the parent category anyway. I try this but get no results:

`$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.title FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.parent_id='$id'");`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870748/joomla-2-5-parent-category-id) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809671/get-category-by-id-of-child-article-joomla-2-5-api) may help you

Comment: This code is from my last answer and you can't use it onetoone for this task.

Comment: gag, in which file do you have this code now?

Comment: Yes, Joomla Agency, I just did not want to bother you so much). So I made another question for this. If you need it I can remove my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(tested and worked in Joomla 3.3.0):

**Put this code:**

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = $item->core_catid;
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.parent_id FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$id'");
$parent_category_id = $db->loadResult();
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.title FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$parent_category_id'");
$parent_category_title = $db->loadResult();
if($parent_category_title != 'ROOT'){
 echo '<p>Parent Category: '.$parent_category_title.'</p>';
}
echo '<p>Parent Category: <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id='.$parent_category_id.'">'.$parent_category_title.'</a></p>';
?>
```

**into this file:**

templates/yourtemplate/html/com_tags/default_items.php

copy from:

components\com_tags\views\tags\tmpl\default_items.php

**between this two lines**

```
<?php foreach ($items as $i => $item) : ?> //Line 63
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Ah, it's fine. It does what needed. And one more question (it's funny to ask you more questions). I want to make my category name to be links to their categories. Can I do it here?

Comment: Can you accept my change for the title. Your title is misleading. This solution is only for the tag view...

Comment: i updated the answer. now with category link...

Comment: Yes I see, but the link leads to somewhere else with 404. I get this url mydomain.com/index.php/component/content/category/35-en/tutorials/art/drawing-and-painting?layout=blog

Comment: Can you check the access level for the parent category?

Comment: The category access level is public, all my categories are public.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14551/discussion-between-joomla-agency-and-gag)

Comment: Can you send me the link to you page?

Comment: Hi, I found where the problem is. For the link to be correct it should look like this - index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=35&Itemid=139 - and there is a problem here. To get the Itemid=139 we need to access in the database __menu and find menu ID. But I could not understand how it makes connections with categories and articles. There are no such tables that mention this connection. Do you have any ideas about this? Thanks.

Comment: I try your url with itemid and then without it and i see the same page.

Comment: The problem is if I generate the code without itemid it gives me the page we were seeing together, and with itemid it gives the correct link, but I cannot find a way to pull it correctly from database.

Comment: That's strange. I test my own code and the generated link is ok by me. Do you use something like sh404sef or can you clean the redirect links in joomla? Maybe a htaccess problem?!

Answer (score 2):

Surely in your article options you can just set 'Show Category', 'Link Category, 'Show Parent' and 'Link Parent' to 'Show' (category) and 'Yes' (link).

Comment: No, it is not in the category, I made my tags result page look like category blog, I managed to do what I wanted except the parent category. I would like to have it also with a link to the parent category.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this using the Content model to load the article.

```
/* Lets say the article ID is stored in $id */

/* Get an instance of the generic articles model */
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel');
$myArticle = $model->getItem($id);

$categoryID = $myArticle->catid; /* catid = "9" */
$category_title = $myArticle->category_title; /* category_title = "Blog" */
$category_alias = $myArticle->category_alias; /* category_alias = "blog" */

$parent_id = $myArticle->parent_id; /* parent_id = "1" */
$parent_title = $myArticle->parent_title; /* parent_title = "ROOT" */
$parent_alias = $myArticle->parent_alias; /* parent_alias = "root" */
```

The values shown in the right-hand side comments are what I just pulled out of a demo install of Joomla 3.3 with the "Blog" sample content installed. ***Note*** the value of the `root` category.

Comment: I do not know whether I place the code correctly, but as I paste it in the same place where my old code with database call was, my site breaks down.